# Jenkins Deploy Plugin: syntax for WAR/EAR path using a parameter

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins 1.602 with Deploy Plugin 1.10, remotely deploying to Tomcat 6.0.29. A single Jenkins job does the build (using Maven) and the remote deployment (Deploy Plugin 1.10).

The Jenkins job will deploy fine when using **/*.war in the 'Deploy war/ear to a container -> WAR/EAR files' field, but I'm not able to use one of the parameters from the (parameterised) Jenkins job. I've tried various fileset selectors however can't get it to work. There are no error messages that I can see, it seems to just miss the deployment step altogether - I assume because it's not finding a file.

I'm wondering if I have the fileset selector syntax incorrect (I don't think so as I've tried multiple combinations), or if this is not possible with this plugin.

The 'WAR/EAR files' goes off the Jenkins job's workspace folder, so **/*.war is getting, and deploying, the following files:

```
../workspace/parameter1/target/*.war
../workspace/parameter2/target/*.war
```

I want to specify which of these folders I'm getting the .war file from so have tried the following without success:

```
${parameter}/target/*.war

/${parameter}/target/*.war

<fileset dir="${parameter}" casesensitive="no"><include name="/target/*.war"/></fileset>

<fileset dir="${parameter}" includes="/target/*.war"><depth max="1"/></fileset>
```

Plus some other fileset combinations but basically more of the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible in Deploy Plugin v1.10 and has been requested:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24876

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5790